# Progress Bar Todo List Tutorial

Tags: python, django

I have been following the light bird beginner's tutorial to Django. [link](http://lightbird.net/dbe/todo_list.html#adding-users)

In the last part of the part 1 tutorial we are tasked with developing a progress bar. I am not able to get this progress bar to work with the following code.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.

class DateTime(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.datetime.strftime("%b %d, %Y, %I:%M %p"))

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    progress = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created = models.ForeignKey(DateTime)
    priority = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    difficulty = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    def mark_done(self):
        return "<a href='%s'>Done</a>" % reverse("todo.views.mark_done", args=[self.pk])
    mark_done.allow_tags = True
    def progress_(self):
        return "<div style='width: 100px; border: 1px solid #ccc;'>" + \
        "<div style='height: 4px; width: %dpx; background: #555; '></div></div>" % self.progress
    progress_.allow_tags = True

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["name", "priority", "difficulty", "created", "done", "user"]
    search_fields = ["name"]

class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Item

class DateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["datetime"]
    inlines = [ItemInline]
    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue='../%s/'):
        """ Determines the HttpResponse for the add_view stage.  """
        for item in Item.objects.filter(created=obj):
            if not item.user:
                item.user = request.user
                item.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("admin:todo_item_changelist"))
        opts = obj._meta
        pk_value = obj._get_pk_val()
        msg = "Item(s) were added successfully."
        # Here, we distinguish between different save types by checking for
        # the presence of keys in request.POST.
        if request.POST.has_key("_continue"):
            self.message_user(request, msg + ' ' + _("You may edit it again below."))
            if request.POST.has_key("_popup"):
                post_url_continue += "?_popup=1"
            return HttpResponseRedirect(post_url_continue % pk_value)

        if request.POST.has_key("_popup"):
            return HttpResponse(
              '<script type="text/javascript">opener.dismissAddAnotherPopup(window, "%s", "%s");'
              '</script>' % (escape(pk_value), escape(obj)))
        elif request.POST.has_key("_addanother"):
            self.message_user(request, msg + ' ' + (_("You may add another %s below.") %
                                                    force_unicode(opts.verbose_name)))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
        else:
            self.message_user(request, msg)

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("admin:todo_item_changelist"))

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
admin.site.register(DateTime, DateAdmin)
```

I do not have any progress bar on my Items page at all like the screenshot from the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple and not addressed in the tutorial at all. In the ItemAdmin class you need to add the list_display for the `"progress_"` function that is defined in the tutorial.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.

class DateTime(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.datetime.strftime("%b %d, %Y, %I:%M %p"))

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    progress = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created = models.ForeignKey(DateTime)
    priority = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    difficulty = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    def mark_done(self):
        return "<a href='%s'>Done</a>" % reverse("todo.views.mark_done", args=[self.pk])
    mark_done.allow_tags = True
    def progress_(self):
        return "<div style='width: 100px; border: 1px solid #ccc;'>" + \
        "<div style='height: 4px; width: %dpx; background: #555; '></div></div>" % self.progress
    progress_.allow_tags = True

class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["name", "priority", "progress_", "difficulty", "created", "done", "user"]
    search_fields = ["name"]

class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Item

class DateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["datetime"]
    inlines = [ItemInline]
    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue='../%s/'):
        """ Determines the HttpResponse for the add_view stage.  """
        for item in Item.objects.filter(created=obj):
            if not item.user:
                item.user = request.user
                item.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("admin:todo_item_changelist"))
        opts = obj._meta
        pk_value = obj._get_pk_val()
        msg = "Item(s) were added successfully."
        # Here, we distinguish between different save types by checking for
        # the presence of keys in request.POST.
        if request.POST.has_key("_continue"):
            self.message_user(request, msg + ' ' + _("You may edit it again below."))
            if request.POST.has_key("_popup"):
                post_url_continue += "?_popup=1"
            return HttpResponseRedirect(post_url_continue % pk_value)

        if request.POST.has_key("_popup"):
            return HttpResponse(
              '<script type="text/javascript">opener.dismissAddAnotherPopup(window, "%s", "%s");'
              '</script>' % (escape(pk_value), escape(obj)))
        elif request.POST.has_key("_addanother"):
            self.message_user(request, msg + ' ' + (_("You may add another %s below.") %
                                                    force_unicode(opts.verbose_name)))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
        else:
            self.message_user(request, msg)

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("admin:todo_item_changelist"))

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
admin.site.register(DateTime, DateAdmin)
```